# Symmetry in Probability: Dropping pins on a line segment; calculate average length of interval

Tags: probability, expected-value, recreational-mathematics

This is from Paul Zeitz, Art and Craft of Problem Solving. Problem 3.1.28, 3rd edition, pg 69.

I quote the problem verbatim: **"Imagine dropping three pins at random on the unit interval [0,1]. They separate the interval into four pieces. What is the average length of the piece.**

I am fully aware of two/three solution on Stack exchange that address the above problem. But I would like to understand the solution presented by the author of the book.

The solution goes as follows: "Imagine that we are not actually dropping three pins on a line segment, but instead dropping 4 pins of a circle with circumference 1 unit. Wherever the fourth point lands, cut the circle there and 'unwrap' it to form the unit interval."

I would like to understand where is symmetry coming into play in the above solution, and how does one arrive at the answer 1/4 by invoking symmetry.

Comment: It may be more *exchangeability* than *symmetry*, but the idea is that it makes no difference to the distributions whether you cut with the initial pin before or after dropping the other pins (clearly equivalent to the original question) or with the final pin (so equivalent too).  The distributions of the individual lengths are therefore  identical (though not independent of each other) since the pins would have been equally likely to be dropped in a different permutation, and so can easily be found.

Comment: Why is the distribution of the individual lengths identical? That is what I am struggling to understand. Why is it not independent?

Comment: Could you please explain this: "are therefore identical (though not independent of each other) since the pins would have been equally likely to be dropped in a different permutation, and so can easily be found"

Comment: They are not independent because the four pieces add up to $1$, so for example if one is $0.8$ the three others are each conditionally constrained to be no more than $0.2$.

Comment: Also, again why is the distribution of individual lengths identical? 

In other words, if interval 1 has length a; interval 2, length b; interval 3, length c; and and interval 4, length d, why is it the case that when you permute/exchange the interval lengths, the probability of 'hitting' the same intervals but in different order -- i.e. interval 1 is now of length b; interval 3 is now of length c, etc -- remains the same?

Comment: Dropping the four pins at (mod $1$ on the circle circumference $1$) the points $0.0, 0.8, 0.85, 0.88$ is as likely as dropping them at $0.85, 0.8, 0.88, 0.0$ or at $0.1, 0.9, 0.95, 0.98$ due the symmetry/exchangeability.  So the distribution of the length above a particularly pin is always $P(L \le x) =1-(1-x)^3$ and density $3(1-x)^2$ no matter which pin or length you are looking at and thus they are identically distributed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147012/discussion-between-s-m-and-henry).

Comment: I do not do chat

Comment: I am sorry, I really would like to understand this properly. So, again how is symmetry coming into play here? If I were to drop the pins at $0.85, 0.8, 0.88, 0.0$, why must it be the case that the probability of dropping them at $0.85, 0.8, 0.88, 0.0$ is the same? Grateful for everything.

Comment: Also, let A be random variable associated with interval, B, be RV associated with interval 2; C and D defined similarly:

Are you saying:  E(A=x) + E(B=x) + E(C=x) + E(D=x) = E(A+B+C+D = 1). But E(A+B+C+D=1) = (1)P(A+B+C+D=1) = 1, as A+B+C+D will always be equal to one, and hence the result follows?

Comment: Pins at $0.0,0.8,0.85,0.88$ and $0.85, 0.8, 0.88, 0.0$ are equally likely drops because he pins are exchangeable (in this particular case they are also independent, though might not be if you were looking at people being seated on a round table)

Comment: But what about drops 0.85,0.8,0.88,0.0 or at 0.1,0.9,0.95,0.98. Why are they equally likely?  Is it because there is nothing "special" that makes one configuration of drops more/less likely as another?

Comment: The book is saying $A+B+C+D = 1$ so $E[A]+E[B]+E[C]+E[D] =E[A+B+C+D]=1$, which is a simple result.  Then using the symmetry/exchangeability/identical distributions, you have $E[A]=E[B]=E[C]=E[D]$ and that means each of those expectations must be $\frac14$.

Comment: Slightly stronger than "nothing special", the pins are dropped independently and uniformly

Comment: Look, suppose only $2$ pins were dropped on a circle. In relation to the first, the second could drop *anywhere*, but on an *average*, you would *expect* it to drop diametrically opposite. The same idea extends when more than two pins are dropped.